# Logic Apps, Azure Function accessing a SQL Database with IP restriction

Tags: database, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App and Azure Function in my Azure tenancy which needs to access a SQL Database in a third party company's Azure tenancy.  The Azure SQL Database is owned and managed by a third party company who require a public IP to restrict access.

My understanding is that Logic Apps and Functions do not have a static outbound public IP address. What solutions do I have to access the SQL Database in Azure in this scenario?

Comment: Initial thoughts are to proxy the request from a Logic App or Azure Function via a proxy server (IAAS) in Azure.  However not sure if this will work with SQL Database

Answer (score 1):

You would need to ask the 3rd party to open up the Azure IP range for the relevant Data Center (region).

You can find the most update to date list [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41653).

Alternatively, you need to move your functions to an Isolated Plan, in which case, you can then assign a static IP. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses):

> **Dedicated IP addresses** If you need static, dedicated IP addresses, we recommend App Service Environments (the Isolated tier of App
>   Service plans). For more information, see App Service Environment IP
>   addresses and How to control inbound traffic to an App Service
>   Environment.

You can also [query the inbound and outbound IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-addresses#find-outbound-ips) for an app service plan.

Comment: Thanks Murray.  The 3rd party are hosting their database in Azure, however they are only willing to open it up to a single static IP.

Looks like the above will work for Azure Function.  Need to look for a solution for a Logic App

Comment: You can get your function to start a logic app... not ideal but may be a solution. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions.md

Comment: I would suggest to have one function doing the SQL part and having the logic app calling the function, this way is easier.